# justify-content: center not working on angular component

Tags: angular

I want to stretch the child component. Why does this not work?

## Parent Component

`<app-tmp></app-tmp>` is a component that I want to stretch but does not stretch, while the same code is not wrapped in component stretches.

```
<div style="width: 100%; display: flex; justify-content: stretch; flex-wrap: wrap; background-color: yellow">

            <p style="height: 50px; width: 100%; background-color: skyblue">This streches</p>

            <app-tmp></app-tmp>
</div>
```

## app-tmp component code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tmp',
  template: `
    <p style="height: 50px; width: 100%; background-color: skyblue">
      This does not stretch
    </p>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./tmp.component.scss']
})
export class TmpComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

### Other information

justify-content: flex-end, etc works, but only justify-content: stretch does not work.

## How it looks like

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Angular components generate a stylesheet for styling of component.
So put the styles in the stylesheet here it is `tmp.component.scss`

```
:host {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: skyblue
}
```

This is somewhat similar to @N.F. answer

Comment: Thank you！ That works. But why "justify-content: stretch" does not work on child component ?

Comment: So add this line after styleUrls: ```encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None```. After importing ViewEncapsulation from ```@angular/core```

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your `tmp.component.scss`.

```
:host {
  width: 100%;
}
```